# Use Excel countifs with unique values

Tags: excel

I have the following sheet:

[image]

I then use the following formula to count the number of each type in each area/country:
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$19,"UK",$C$2:$C$19,"A") and I get the following result:
[image]

My problem is that I only want the same name to be counted once per area/country, therefore the value for UK / A should be 4, not 8. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Regards
Crouz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a `pivot` on a `pivot`. Both should be in classic pivot table format.

Let me walk you through the logic:

#### 1st Pivot

Pivot your initial data. Format pivot to be classic (right click -> PivotTable Options -> Display -> Classic .. -> ok)

As Row labels have `Location`, `Type` and `Name`. in Values put anything you want i have chosen `count of Name`.

Remove subtotals, grand totals from pivot and Repeat item labels or columns `Location` and `Type`(i am assuming you have excel >= 2010). http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1964-excel-repeat-item-labels.html

#### 2nd pivot

Pivot your 1st pivots data. Pivot to classic view. in Row Labels have `Location` and `Type` and in values whatever you want os `count` i have chosen `count of Location`. Remove sub/grand totals and repeat items and your done.

This is what i have

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, it was exactly what I was looking for. Your walk through was second to none, and I learned something in the process. All the best. Crouz

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate your name/location columns and do your countif using that. It's not pretty, but it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to remove the duplicates. On the *data* tab, click on *remove duplicates*. It will then all you for the criteria to use. Select all three columns. It should then work as you expect

Comment: I cannot remove duplicates, I need that data for other charts and graphs, but thank you for your time on this matter. Regards, Crouz